# How to open virtual box in full screen?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed Ubuntu *14.04* in my virtual box with Virtual Machine config 3 Gb ram.

- *My host OS is windows 8.1 pro. 64 bit.*
- *I am using 64 bit Ubuntu.*

Let me know if you need any more details as I am new to Linux.

After so many attempts to **duel boot Ubuntu** (No wifi connectivity for my system in duel boot), I came back to virtual box.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate full screen by pressing combination on keyboard "Host + F". In my notebook, the host key is the right Ctrl button, so I press Right Ctrl + F buttons. Give it a try.